# get JSON var value in python

Tags: python, json

In Python, what is the easiest way to extract a line containing a JavaScript variable definition and get the value assigned to it (I'm scraping the JavaScript from webpages using BeautifulSoup), which is contained within curly braces (i.e. {, }), keeping in mind that the variable itself may contain any several levels of nested curly braces within it.

For e.g. with the input

```
var myVar  =  { "a": "123","b":"345", "c": {"c1":20,"c2":"c123", "c3": {"c3_1": {"c3_1_1":"12"}}}, "d":21, "e":["1","2"]}
```

I would like to get the complete `myVar` value as a `string` (as I want to convert this to a Python `list` after that),

```
{ "a": "123","b":"345", "c": {"c1":20,"c2":"c123", "c3": {"c3_1": {"c3_1_1":"12"}}}, "d":21, "e":["1","2"]}
```

Any help would be great as I am new to Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.index` to find where json object start and `re.sub` (makes `"a": "123"` from `a:"123"`) with `str.replace` (changes single quotes to double quotes here: `['1','2']`) to fix json:

```
import json
import re

var = '''var myVar  =  { a: "123",b:"345", c: {c1:20,c2:"c123", c3: {c3_1: {c3_1_1:"12"}}}, d:21, e:['1','2']}'''
v = var[var.index('{'):]
v = re.sub(r'(\w*):', r'"\1":', v)
v = v.replace('\'', '\"')

>>> v
'{ "a": "123","b":"345", "c": {"c1":20,"c2":"c123", "c3": {"c3_1": {"c3_1_1":"12"}}}, "d":21, "e":["1","2"]}'
>>> json.loads(v)
{u'a': u'123', u'c': {u'c3': {u'c3_1': {u'c3_1_1': u'12'}}, u'c2': u'c123', u'c1': 20}, u'b': u'345', u'e': [u'1', u'2'], u'd': 21}
```

Comment: Thanks, that does seem to work. Would be nice to have an explanation.

Comment: Hmm.. when the 'name' in the JSON object is surrounded by quotes (i.e. { "a":"123"...}) this gives an error.

Comment: @source.rar error from `json.loads`? what json string you tested?

Comment: I've updated it in the question above (as per the JSON spec names need to be strings i.e. double quoted)

Comment: @source.rar with updated string all is working without `re.sub` and `str.replace` ofcourse

Answer (score 1):

```
import json
a = json.dumps(myVar)
```

The variable `a` is of the type string in this example. You can manipulate it as you like.

Comment: I do plan to use the json library, but could you explain how I could get 'var' in this case from the text?

Comment: With the `eval` you could do it easily

Comment: Are you asking how to get the value of myVar through beautiful soup?

Comment: With the input string mentioned in my question, how can I get the output mentioned (as a string which I could then convert to a list with the json library)?

Comment: I've made an edit to the above to show how json.dumps works. It outputs a string, so `a` is now the entire string of myVar.